# Browser's webpage able to zoom in and zoom out

Tags: android, html, zooming

I am developing an android application which requires to ***open url link in web browser with zoom in and zoom out*** control (i.e, Chrome)
For Zoom in and zoom out facility i found one [solution](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/115042/220302) but i want to set zoom in and zoom out functionality programmatically.

**I do not want to use android WebView for load webpages.**

```
try {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.mds-foundation.org/mdsmanager/help"));
        startActivity(myIntent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No application can handle this request. Please install a web browser",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to Android Webview for open url, Then you can set chrome custom tab for opening Url in your application.

[Check this link](https://segunfamisa.com/posts/chrome-custom-tabs)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set zoom level while using the intent Intent.ACTION_VIEW.
The solution that you are referring is handling zoom level inside the App only. This is not possible with firing intent.

If you want to use Android WebView then you can do it like this

```
public class MyBrowser extends Activity {

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

    String loadUrl = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
    int scale = 60; //scale is percent of zoom level you want

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setInitialScale(scale);

    try {
        webView.loadUrl(loadUrl);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

in your layout file you can define the webview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can use WebView. Its Simple you can call mWebView.setInitialScale(ZOOM_LEVEL); where ZOOM_LEVEL is the percent value of zoom you want

Comment: I know browser zooming is only possible with Webview but client do not want to use Webview for loading webpage